# Does a Markov Blanket allow connections between Parents of a Node?

Tags: probability, markov-chains, bayesian, markov-process, bayes-theorem

In a Markov Blanket, we can connect the childredn of a node between them, as a child can be parent (or spouse) of another child. Does this rule apply as well for Parents of a node?

In advance, Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the parents of a node can be connected to each other as well. This doesn't change the Markov Blanket.